# Postgres как вернуть деление чисел?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Как запросом проверить оба ли числа существуют и второе число не равно нулю?

```
  select x/y
```

Comment: CASE?​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: такой?         CASE
            WHEN t0.cao IS NOT NULL AND t0.sio2 IS NOT NULL AND
                t0.sio2::numeric <> 0::numeric THEN round(t0.cao::numeric / t0.sio2::numeric, 2)
            ELSE NULL::numeric
        END AS "FBASE",

Comment: Вы отметили вариант с `IF` как верный для себя, но, в `postgresql` на сколько я знаю нет такой конструкции. Может быть Вы ошиблись тегом и вместо `postgresql` Вам нужен `mysql`?

Comment: клацнул не глядя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще Вы можете использовать функцию `nullif`, которая вернет `null` если `y` будет равен нулю:

```
select x/nullif(y,0)
```

[Sql Fiddle пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/3732)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT IF(CONCAT(x,y)=CONCAT(x*1,y*1) AND y*1<>0, x/y, NULL);`